# How to make 2D stabilization in Movie Clip Editor only follow active tracks?

Tags: video

When using Blender and the Movie Clip Editor to stabilize a clip, I can select multiple tracking markers and have them follow the tracks for 2D stabilization, etc.

Now, I have a shot, where features come into shot one after another, and I'd like to have stabilization be based on them. Not all track markers are visible throughout the whole shot, so they become active for the section they're visible in, and are otherwise disabled.

When adding all these tracks to the 2D stabilization list, Blender creates the median of all the tracks, even the disabled ones. Is there a way to make it only follow the currently active tracks, and disregard tracks that are not active in the current frame?

And if so, how?

Comment: Related: [Track, Match, Blend!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Df3TAZ-VNso&list=PLtuvwW4VAp5tu2RdbRHThM6FVFfvFur1g&index=4)

Comment: Related: [Blender Guru Introduction to Camera Tracking](http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/introduction-to-camera-tracking/)

Comment: Instead of creating a new Marker, just offset the old one. It should retain its center of origin but rely on new image data.

Answer (score 2):

You can continue to track past an obstruction in the frame, or track a new feature by using the Offset value of the active Marker. Go to the Properties panel and look for Marker > Offset:  simply change these values to position the Marker boundary over the new feature and continue to track.

[image: Change Offset values to locate new feature]